# How to find an invoice number in a sheet than an item in the list of the items of the invoice to get the sold numbers of the item

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I have a list of invoice numbers in a column. In another sheet I have the same invoice numbers but with items in another column and a third with sold numbers.
I'd like to get this sales data in the first sheet as a stock management. I tried it with double `vlookup` and `iferror` but cannot solve the problem.

Sample:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ilGQG5umhHXY483vEiQX2esHCulLytK4uIXfAgNkU8E/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single `VLOOKUP` (in each of `B3`, `E3`, `H3` etc)

```
=INDEX(IFERROR(VLOOKUP((A3:A&B1),{Sheet2!A3:A&Sheet2!B3:B,Sheet2!C3:C},2,0)))
```

---

The formulas work by creating 2 *"helper columns"* like `A3:A&B1` and `Sheet2!A3:A&Sheet2!B3:B`.
We also change cell `B1` to `E1`, `H1` etc.

*(**Do** adjust the formulae according to your ranges and locale)*

[image]

Comment: Wow, marvellous, thank you very much!
Great help!

Comment: Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it so others can benefit as well. You can even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) the answer. If you don't have enough reputation, your upvote will show up later, once you reach [enough reputation points](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up).